# C Fork program output explanation

Tags: c, unix, buffer, fork

I have a program in C which utilizes the `fork()` system call:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void doit(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    fork();
    fork();
    printf("Unix System Programming\n");
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    doit();
    printf("WTF\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Now, this program gives me 8 lines of output. I think that is because of two forks 2^2 = 4 Times * 2 Print Statement = 8 Times. If I am wrong, please correct me and explain why.

Now, the question is why am I getting different outputs on each run? Let's say I execute this code: the first time I get output

```
Unix System Programming
WTF
Unix System Programming
Unix System Programming
Unix System Programming
WTF
WTF
WTF
```

and the 2nd time I get:

```
Unix System Programming
WTF
Unix System Programming
Unix System Programming
WTF
Unix System Programming
WTF
WTF
```

And third time again different. Why does this happen? I am clueless; kindly explain in detail.

Comment: Unused variable `pid` in `doit()`.  The `return` in the function is not necessary either.

Answer (score 3):

When you fork a new process, the parent and child both run concurrently. The order that they execute their respective `printf()` statements is unpredictable -- sometimes the parent will print first, sometimes the child will.

You might understand better if you included the PID in the output, so you could see which process is printing each line. SO change it to:

```
printf("%d: Unix System Programming\n", getpid());
```

and

```
printf("%d: WTF\n", getpid());
```

What you should see is that each process prints `Unix System Programming` before `WTF`, but the order of processes will be mixed up.

Comment: Okay @Barmar ! Would like to know one additional thing, if i have two forks in this program, so i can expect atleast 4 Child processes running & One parent process (which is the code execution itself) .. And here, there are total 2 print statement . Hence 4*2 = 8 times output .Am i correct or is the case different ?

Comment: If you have 2 forks, you get 4 total processes, not 4 child processes. The first fork creates 1 child. The second fork is run in both the parent and child, and they each create 1 new process. So you end up with 1 original process, 2 child processes, 1 grandchild process.

Comment: But you're correct that each of them prints 2 lines, so you get 8 output lines.

Answer (score 2):

The outputs that you are seeing are from different processes. Once `fork` has succeeded, you get a different child process (as well as the parent process). Since they are from different processes, you can't guarantee when one process gets its turn and executes. So the outputs of different processes get intermixed and the order might be different at each run.

If you want to make sure that parent and child processes run in some specific order then you have to synchronize them, which is typically a lot more work than just forking. (It will probably require a wait operation or the use of pipes — depending on the nature of synchronization that you want.)